# Can I run the bundle open command inside of MacVim?

Tags: ruby, vim, bundler

When I issue the `bundle open` command in the terminal, the "vi" editor comes up, but it doesn't seem to have all the defaults and settings I'm used to, and it looks fairly ugly as well. Is there a way to have `bundle open` start-up in MacVim outside the terminal, or can I issue `bundle open` in MacVim so it comes up there?

Comment: You probably need to set your `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variable to the path to macvim.

Answer (score 2):

You can have `bundle open` send the file to MacVim for you. First, you need to make sure the `mvim` script that comes with MacVim is installed; instructions [here](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/FAQ).

Then, as @Randy Morris said in a comment, you need to set your EDITOR environment variable to `mvim`. You could add that to your `.bash_profile` file in your home directory to make it permanent; pretty much every Unix command that launches an editor will use it.